# Linux/Unix Scripting - strangest behaviour ever in a few lines - variable set but empty

Tags: linux, scripting, environment-variables, pvm

I can tell you this is the craziest thing I have seen in a long time.

I have this (part of) sh script running on CentOS 5.4:

```
# Check GOLD_DIR`
echo $GOLD_DIR"<--"
#export GOLD_DIR=/share/apps/GOLD_Suite/GOLD <uncommenting this line works!!
if [ "X$GOLD_DIR" =  "X" ] ; then
  echo "ERROR: GOLD_DIR is (probably) not set on host ${HostName}" >> ${3}
  exit 1
fi
```

And this gives the following output:

```
/share/apps/GOLD_Suite/GOLD<-- 
Waiting for 5 seconds ..... Testing output

The test script did spawn a job (i.e. PVM ran OK), 
but errors were detected in the test script output 
on the host machine: Below is the output

ERROR: GOLD_DIR is (probably) not set on host xxx.yyy.local
```

As you can see the `GOLD_DIR` variable is set (the script finds it as shown by the output with postfixed "`<--`") !  If I uncomment the export of the `GOLD_DIR` variable in the script code (first snippet) everything works.

EDIT: `GOLD_DIR` is exported in `/etc/profile` (using `export GOLD_DIR=/share/apps/GOLD_Suite/GOLD`)

Any ideas why?

Note1: I don't know if this is important but this is a spawn script on PVM.

Note2: The script is written in sh `#!/bin/sh` but I am using bash...

**Edit3: I GOT IT TO WORK BUT I DONT KNOW WHY!** - Ok so what I did was rename the hostname (with `sudo hostname abc`) to the name of the machine I ssh into (e.g. abc).  Before the PVM was listing the full name of the machine `abc.mycompany.local`.  Note that both `abc.mycompany.local` and `abc` are the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

So the var is set. If you just do `export GOLD_DIR` instead of commented line (without setting the value), will it work?

Also. It's an isolated case? Is it bash there on CentOS? Try to use [[ ]] to check what's working wrong.

Comment: No it does not work.  I can see the variable contents if I do an echo right after your statement but I still get the ERROR: ... bit.

Comment: I am using bash - but the script shbang is #!/bin/sh.  I've changed to [[ ]] instead of [] and I still get the darn error

Comment: @MalteseUnderdog: So it's something with a variable value probably... Can you try `declare -p` on it? Maybe there's something suspicious about it. If you split the working export GOLD_DIR=blabla to assignment and then export, will it change something? Also try with POSIX mode like in POSIXLY_CORRECT envvar. If you change the condition to `[ -z "$GOLD_DIR" ]`, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it might have something to do with the non-interactive nature of the job. Jobs run from shell scripts won't necessarily source /etc/profile, so they might not be picking up your ${GOLD_DIR} variable. (Unless you've explicitly changed its behavior, bash will only source /etc/profile for a login shell.)

Try adding:

```
. /etc/profile
```

in the beginning of your script just to see if that changes anything. If not, when you echo the error statement, add in ${GOLD_DIR} somewhere to see if the variable is still available in that statement.